# How to optimize my loops if I already have loops that iterate over once

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell. I have created a script to copy files according to year & month, and then zip it. My code is working fine, because I am noob in powershell, and just wrote same command again and again. Can someone help me reduce my lines in the codes?

```
$Source = "C:\Users\abhishek.y.verma\OneDrive - Accenture\Desktop\My-Info"
$Target = "C:\Users\abhishek.y.verma\OneDrive - Accenture\Desktop\Power"

$Year1 = 2022
$Year2 = 2021
$Year3 = 2020
$Year4 = 2019
$Year5 = 2018


$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Source -Recurse -File 

#Get the names of the files
$filesFromYear1 = $files | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Year -eq $Year1}
$filesFromYear2 = $files | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Year -eq $Year2}
$filesFromYear3 = $files | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Year -eq $Year3}
$filesFromYear4 = $files | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Year -eq $Year4}





#Make Folder for each month
foreach($i in 1..12) {
    New-Item -Path $Target\$Year1 -Name $i -ItemType "directory"
    New-Item -Path $Target\$Year2 -Name $i -ItemType "directory"
    New-Item -Path $Target\$Year3 -Name $i -ItemType "directory"
    New-Item -Path $Target\$Year4 -Name $i -ItemType "directory"
    New-Item -Path $Target\$Year5 -Name $i -ItemType "directory"

}

#Move Files:

foreach($j in 1..12) {
    $filesMonthly1 = $files | Where-Object  { ($_.CreationTime.Year -eq $Year1) -and ($_.CreationTime.Month -eq $j) }
    $filesMonthly1 | Copy-Item -Destination $Target\$Year1\$j
    Compress-Archive -Path $Target\$Year1\$j -Destination $Target\$Year1\$j.zip
    $filesMonthly2 = $files | Where-Object  { ($_.CreationTime.Year -eq $Year2) -and ($_.CreationTime.Month -eq $j) }
    $filesMonthly2 | Copy-Item -Destination $Target\$Year2\$j
    Compress-Archive -Path $Target\$Year2\$j -Destination $Target\$Year2\$j.zip
    $filesMonthly3 = $files | Where-Object  { ($_.CreationTime.Year -eq $Year3) -and ($_.CreationTime.Month -eq $j) }
    $filesMonthly3 | Copy-Item -Destination $Target\$Year3\$j
    Compress-Archive -Path $Target\$Year3\$j -Destination $Target\$Year3\$j.zip
    $filesMonthly4 = $files | Where-Object  { ($_.CreationTime.Year -eq $Year4) -and ($_.CreationTime.Month -eq $j) }
    $filesMonthly4 | Copy-Item -Destination $Target\$Year4\$j
    Compress-Archive -Path $Target\$Year4\$j -Destination $Target\$Year4\$j.zip
    $filesMonthly5 = $files | Where-Object  { ($_.CreationTime.Year -eq $Year5) -and ($_.CreationTime.Month -eq $j) }
    $filesMonthly5 | Copy-Item -Destination $Target\$Year5\$j
    Compress-Archive -Path $Target\$Year5\$j -Destination $Target\$Year5\$j.zip
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Where-Object` *once*, to test that the year is *one of the years* you're interested in, then use `Group-Object` to group them all together - at which point you just need to repeat the same operation for each group:

```
$Source = "C:\Users\abhishek.y.verma\OneDrive - Accenture\Desktop\My-Info"
$Target = "C:\Users\abhishek.y.verma\OneDrive - Accenture\Desktop\Power"

$Years = 2022..2019

# discover files in scope
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Source -Recurse -File |Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Year -in $Years}

# group by creation year
$files |Group-Object { $_.CreationTime.Year } |ForEach-Object {
  # extract year of current group
  $year = $_.Name

  foreach($month in 1..12){
    # create the target directory
    $newMonthFolder = New-Item -Path $Target\$year -Name $month -ItemType "directory"

    # copy relevant files
    $_.Group |Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Month -eq $month} |Copy-Item -Destination $newMonthFolder.FullName

    # create zip
    Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $newMonthFolder.FullName -Destination $Target\$Year\$month.zip
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
$Source = "C:/Users/Megam/Desktop/A-1"
$Target = "C:/Users/Megam/Desktop/B-1"
$initialYear = 2018
$finalYear = 2022

$validFiles = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Source -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Year -in ($initialYear..$finalYear)}
($initialYear..$finalYear) | ForEach-Object {
    $year = $_
    $files = $validFiles | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Year -eq $year} # Get files of year.
    if($files.Count -gt 0) # If there are files
    {
        New-Item -Path "$Target\$year" -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null # Create Directory - Year 
    }
    (1..12) | ForEach-Object{
        $month = $_
        $monthFiles = $files | Where-Object{ $_.CreationTime.Month -eq $month }
        if($monthFiles.Count -gt 0) # If there are files
        {
            $dest = "$Target/$year/$month"
            New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null # Create Directory - Month 
            $monthFiles | ForEach-Object{
                Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $dest -Force
                Write-Host "File: $_ , Year: $year, Month: $month, Destination: $dest/$($_ | Split-Path -Leaf)" #Remove this line in production
            }
            Compress-Archive -Path "$dest/*.*" -Destination "$dest/files-$year-$month.zip" -Force # Create Zip file
        }
    }
}
```

`$_` it refers to object in current context, between(inside) curly braces.
for example `Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $year}` in this case `$_` is a file object, not `int` value from `ForEach-Object{ ..... }` context, previously I store the year value in `$year` variable for use in `Where-Object{ ..... }`context.
Same case for `$month` variable.

> REMEMBER to remove this line in the code `Write-Host "File: $_ , Year: $year, Month: $month, Destination: $dest/$($_ | Split-Path -Leaf)" #Remove this line in production`, this line can slow down the execution in case of having many files

**Example Output**
***Initial files***
[image: files]
***execution***
[image: output]
***result files***
[image]